# Is it possible to add response time to uvicorn logs for FastApi?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn

My logger looks something like this:

```
log_config = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "%(asctime)s::%(levelname)s::%(name)s::%(filename)s::%(funcName)s::%(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z",
            "use_colors": False,
        },
        "access": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z",
            "fmt": '%(asctime)s::%(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(msecs)d %(status_code)s',
            "use_colors": False,
        },
    },
    "handlers":
    {
        "default":
        {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": 'logging.FileHandler',
            "filename": CONFIG[SECTION]["default"]
        },
        "access":
        {
            "formatter": "access",
            "class": 'logging.FileHandler',
            "filename": CONFIG[SECTION]["access"]
        },
    },
    "loggers":
    {
        "uvicorn": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": False},
        "uvicorn.access": {"handlers": ["access"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": False},
    }
}
```

Start config:

```
uvicorn.run(
    app="app.main:app",
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=8000,
    reload=True,
    log_config=log_config,
    proxy_headers=True,
    forwarded_allow_ips='*',
    log_level="info"
)
```

I don't see a way to add response time in the access format. I also can't seem to find a default list of params anywhere. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create some custom logs as well for FastAPI, and I ended up using a middleware to get the result I wanted.

You can find a full tutorial on how to this [here](https://medium.com/@dhavalsavalia/fastapi-logging-middleware-logging-requests-and-responses-with-ease-and-style-201b9aa4001a).

Basically instead of including your logger in the FastAPI class, you include it as a middleware.

Instead of:

```py
uvicorn.run(
    app="app.main:app",
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=8000,
    reload=True,
    log_config=log_config,
    proxy_headers=True,
    forwarded_allow_ips='*',
    log_level="info"
)
```

Use an approach like this:

```py
app.add_middleware(
    RouterLoggingMiddleware,
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a FastAPI [Middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) that would intersept the process just before the response to log using the `uvicorn.access` logger.

To access the corresponding logger, you will use [`getLogger("name")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger):

> Return a logger with the specified name or, if name is None, return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy. If specified, the name is typically a dot-separated hierarchical name like ‘a’, ‘a.b’ or ‘a.b.c.d’. Choice of these names is entirely up to the developer who is using logging.

A simple example to achieve this:

```
access_logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access")

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_to_access_file(request, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception:
        # Handle potential exceptions if you like
    finally:
        access_logger.info(f"Call finished at {datetime.utcnow().isoformat()}")
```

You can augment the example in various ways. One that I would suggest is to give each call a [uuid4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) in order to recognize the timings afterward in the log file:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def log_to_access_file(request, call_next):
    try:
        request.state.log_id = str(uuid4())
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception:
        # Handle potential exceptions if you like
    finally:
        access_logger.info(f"Request with ID: {request.sate.log_id} finished at {datetime.utcnow().isoformat()}")
```